# Is there any way to change hardhat running environment (hre) provider when running script?

Tags: ether, hardhat, evm

I'm running multiple hardhat nodes in different ports like: 0.0.0.0:8545, ...:8546, ...
My scripts is something like this and I use it in a nestjs project

```
import * as hre from 'hardhat';

async execute(port: number, from: string, to: string, txData: any) {
       // const provider = new hre.ethers.JsonRpcProvider(`http://0.0.00:${port}`);
       // change hre.ethers.provider => provider
        const sender = await hre.ethers.getImpersonatedSigner(from);
        const txData = {
          to: to,
          data: txData,
        };
    const tx = await sender.sendTransaction(txData);
}
```

hardhat.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "localhost1",
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  networks: {
    localhost1: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545",
    },
    localhost2: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8546",
    },
  },
}
```

I tried:

```
hre.ethers.provider = provider;
```

and the issue is:

```
Type 'JsonRpcProvider' is missing the following properties from type 'HardhatEthersProvider': _hardhatProvider, _networkName, _isHardhatNetworkCached, _latestBlockNumberPolled, and 25 more
```

My issue is: I can't change hre.ethers.provider to my custom provider, it always point to the default network came from hardhat config is localhost1. Is there anyway to set provider for hre?
I know we can change provider of sender by `sender.connect(provider)`, but `hre.ethers.getImpersonatedSigner` still point to localhost1 and I will get error `unknown account`. I want to change provider inside hre.